# Rounding floating point numbers to closest multiple of 0.005 with rounding to 3 decimal digits is producing a weird output

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I wrote a small piece of code that rounds a number to the closest multiple of 0.005
but it produces a weird output, that I didn't expect.
I am using Python version `3.7.3`

Here is the code:

```
number = 1.639
print(5 * round(number / 5, 3))
```

Output

```
1.6400000000000001
```

Expected output

```
1.64
```

Check this [replit](https://repl.it/repls/PungentAdoredMatch) for detailed output on different values.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: in this cas, is the output should be *1.640* ?

Comment: @codrelphi , That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(round(5 * round(1.639 / 5, 3), 3))
```

Round it again since according to what I see you are multiplying the rounded number by 5 then you expect that the number to be rounded. I guess you should round the output of the first rounding step!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the multiplication on the rounding number, here is how you can do:

```
number = 1.639
temp = round(number / 5, 3)
final = round(5 * temp, 3)

print(final) # 1.64
```

If you just want to round the final result, here is how you can do it:

```
number = 1.639
final = round(5 * (number / 5), 3)
print(final) # 1.639
```